# Should fascism be banned as a subject?

Tags: discussion, scope

I think we should ban all discussion on these topics:

- Fascism
- Jet fuel, jews etc
- The holocaust
- Whether fascism is leftwing or not

I have never seen a good discussion and they always go off the rails.

Comment: Can you provide examples of posts that "always go off the rails"? Banning whole subjects is, ironically a bit fascist :) but banning all discussion of a group of people, Jews, is outright racist and I don't understand why you think that is OK?

Comment: For example, "there are precisely zero soviet holocaust photos" or "the nazis in holcoaust photos are always in soviet uniforms"

Comment: Links please...

Comment: They're everywhere

Comment: Then it should be no problem for you to provide sources for your question, it really is not much to ask.

Comment: You mean, like https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/242394 or https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/255014 or https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/249594 or https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/251565?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, discussion is already sort-of banned; see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) .

Second, questions about these topics are rightfully held to a higher standard on Stack Exchange. They must demonstrate some research in the topic and be (however hard that is to define) of 'academic' interest. We, all humans in this world, can't deny our collective history and should be able to talk about it in a neutral way that doesn't offend people. Only by learning from past mistakes we can avoid similar mistakes in the future.

Comment: But basically all holocaust threads are trolled to death

Comment: It might attract *some* trolls, but they're usually dealt with quickly through flags.

Answer (score 1):

You mention topics, like the holocoust, that must remain debatable in a democracy. And StackExchange is lagerly a democratic network. This may sound a little bit dramatic, but I would go so far that even if all resources of moderation are exhausted, it must be ensured that such topics can be discussed.